# Как обновить пакеты в самом (!) Nuget? (не для конкретного солюшена)

Tags: c#, update, package, nuget

Пакеты периодически устаревают и при создании нового решения, приходится их обновлять чтобы все было тип-топ.
Кто знает как сделать так, чтобы Nuget сам по мере выхода обновлений их подтягивал, ну или хотя бы на данный момент обновить все пакеты внутри самого Nuget?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что понимать под "самим Nuget"? Пакеты скачиваются для каждого проекта индивидуально.

Comment: Что значит "в самом Nuget"? У вас поднят свой Nuget-сервер?

Comment: Обычный проект, обычный Nuget, понятно что для каждого они скачиваються отдельно, но хочется чтобы те которые уже по умолчанию идут в самой сборке Nuget были уже свежих версий. Это нужно чтобы не терять время на обновление существующих пакетов для нового солюшена. *Гляньте скрин!)

Comment: @YanLinkin: То, что вы показываете, это не nuget, это окно пакетного менеджера. Разница примерно такая, как между интернетом и окном браузера.

Comment: мне кажется автоматическое обновление может оказаться плохой идеей для продакшн решения

Comment: Можно в `Package Manager Console` обновить все пакеты во всех проектах до последней "безопасной" версии одной командой `Update-Package -Safe`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, то что надо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос: Можно в Package Manager Console обновить все пакеты во всех проектах до последней "безопасной" версии одной командой Update-Package -Safe
Спасибо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184217/alexander-petrov!